# Migrate apache kafka polling to spring kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

In a spring-boot (version 2.1.4) application, there is requirement to  migrate apache-kafka to spring-kafka. 
Current kafka consumer does:
1) KafkaConsumer bean initialized at the time of application up
2) It has "0" topic partition set
3) poll the data using apache kafkaConsumer into ConsumerRecord 
4) The application its own has Retry mechanism to wait and poll again till max_retry

The legacy code looks below:

```
 while (!done.get()) {
    ConsumerRecords<byte[], <byte[]> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(<MAX_VALUE>);
    if (records.isEmpty()) {
        retryCount++;
        Thread.sleep(<some_time>);
    } else {
    // Process records;
    }
    if (retryCount > <max_retry_count>) {
    done.set(true); 
    }    
  }
```

Tried below approaches:
1) Using spring kafka annotation (@KafkaListener), but it does not let us have control over polling.
2) Created "ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer" and setupMessageListener adds records into queue for polling. This gives us control on consumer.

I wanted to know, am I heading towards correct direction? 
What would be better solution to achieve above requirement using spring-kafka?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "control on consumer". Creating a container is the same as using a `@KafkaListener` (a container is created under the covers).

Spring uses a "message-driven" approach.

You can set the `idleEventInterval` and the container will publish a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` if no records are received during that time. You can listen for these events with an `ApplicationListener` bean, or an `@EventListener` method.

Comment: Thanks Gary. The "control on consumer" means we would need to start kafka consumer on particular event only. Using @KafkaListener does not have that leverage, hence with KafkaMessageListenerContainer's start() method we can start the kafka consumer container on that event only.

Comment: You have the same "control" over `@KafkaListener`s - see [`@KafkaListener` Lifecycle Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle) in the documentation.